# DATEDIFF Current/Date for Last Record

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a table "Report" with relevant columns "Date", "Doctor". Each doctor appears several times throughout the table. The following code is what I have at current:

```
SET @variable = (SELECT Date FROM Report WHERE Doctor='DocName' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1)
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),@variable) AS DiffDate
```

This gives me the DATEDIFF for one doctor, without name. Is there any way to loop through the table, find the last row/date for each doctor, then perform a DATEDIFF on each individual doctor outputting a list of doctors with their DATEDIFFs (against current date) next to them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use group by to get only 1 row per doctor and max to select latest date:

```
select `Doctor`, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),max(`Date`))
from `Report`
group by `Doctor`
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'd upvote if I had the rep for it! I ended up having to add in "AS DiffDate" between select and from lines in order to get it to actually display the sought data rather than empty columns.